# Play .Wav sound only once on switch change

Tags: switch, sound

I have a project where if you change the value of the spdt switch the colour of the LEDs change. As well as this a .wav file plays. The problem is I only want the .wav to play once. At the moment it constantly plays over and over as it's within the loop. I've tried using a mute or disabling the pin after the play through but I am unable to re-enable so I scrapped it. I deally I want to keep the SPDT switch due to asthetics instead of a push switch. This is my code:

```
#include <TMRpcm.h>
#include <SD.h>                       
#define SD_ChipSelectPin 10             
#include <SPI.h>

TMRpcm tmrpcm;

void setup() 
{
// put your setup code here, to run once:

tmrpcm.speakerPin=9;                          
Serial.begin(9600);
if(!SD.begin(SD_ChipSelectPin))
{
  Serial.println("SD fail");
  return;
}
     tmrpcm.setVolume(6);
     tmrpcm.play("1.wav");
     while (tmrpcm.isPlaying()) {
     delay(1);
}
     tmrpcm.setVolume(6);
     tmrpcm.play("3.wav");
//set the switch input, pin 8, as an 
pinMode(8, INPUT);

//set both the LED pins, pin 5 and 6 as OUTPUTs 
pinMode (5, OUTPUT); 
pinMode (6, OUTPUT); 
 delay(1000);
}

void loop() 
{
 int switchValue = digitalRead(8);
 if (switchValue == 1)
{
   while (tmrpcm.isPlaying()) {
   delay(1);
}
  tmrpcm.setVolume(6);
  tmrpcm.play("4.wav");
  digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(6,LOW);

}
else
{
   while (tmrpcm.isPlaying()) {
   delay(1);
}
   digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(5,LOW);
   tmrpcm.setVolume(6);
   tmrpcm.play("5.wav");

}
}
```

how can I make the wav play once but when the switch changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a variable to hold the "last state" of the switch. Compare that *last state* to the current state as obtained by `switchValue = digitalRead(8)`.

Only call the play function if the old value and the current value are different.

Comment: Hi I added this:  if (switchValue != lastButtonState)
                  {
                       tmrpcm.setVolume(6);
                       tmrpcm.play("4.wav");
                   
                          while (tmrpcm.isPlaying()) {
                      delay(1);}    
                  }
                   
                  lastButtonState = switchValue;

I added it on both sides of my If Statement and It worked :-)